# Merlin plugin for Ocaml with VIM : autocompile the file when saving

Tags: vim, ocaml, merlin

I recently installed Ocaml and its Merlin plugin for a university course. I am using Vim as a text editor. I have heard that it is possible to configure Merlin to compile automatically the .ml file when saving, but I can not find anything about that with a web research, and the professor is using emacs so he can not give me any information about how to activate this feature.

Comment: How do you compile the ml files. Do you use `makefile` or normal `ocaml` in CLI?

Comment: I use a command similar to     `ocamlopt -o helloWorld helloWorld.ml`     and then     `./helloWorld`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is plain vanilla vim style, not relating to merlin. May be you can read merlin document for merlin specific configuration. Set the following in your `~/.vimrc`

Use a key like <kbd>F5</kbd> to achieve it

```
autocmd filetype ocaml nnoremap <F5> :!ocamlopt % -o %:r && ./%:r <CR>
```

This will compile and run executable when you hit <kbd>F5</kbd>.

---

If you prefer `makeprg` option, keep the following autocommand in your vimrc

```
au filetype ocaml set makeprg=ocamlopt\ -o\ %<\ %
set aw
```

and then `:make` when you open your ml file. I would prefer this approach